# Need "last updated" date in RSS feed

Tags: feeds

I need to output the "Content: Changed" field in an RSS feed so the system can tell whether or not the node has been updated. The Block display shows the date perfectly; the feed outputs nothing. Definitely looks like a bug. any ideas? Thanks in advance! (Drupal 10, BTW.)

Comment: If you think this is a bug in core, please post an issue in the core queue so it can be addressed.

Comment: Is "is this a bug?" the question you are asking?

Comment: Yes, I'd love to post this to the core queue, but I don't know how. It's easily reproducible. Any help greatly appreciated, and yes, I am willing to pay for someone's time. This is a show-stopper on a major project. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Really? Well it is right here: https://www.drupal.org/node/add/project-issue/drupal Include explicit steps to reproduce from a "clean" install that you actually verify, or the bug report will go nowhere.

Comment: Thanks - much appreciated. Wish me luck! :) https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3432223

Comment: It's a question, not a bug.